# Powershell exports csv file containing active directory security group data

Tags: powershell, csv, batch-file, active-directory

I have a bat file that starts up a PS1 script, the PS1 script is supposed to go to AD and export the names listed in a Security Group. It runs fine and exports fine, however the data is incorrect, almost as if it is exporting some unknown data that I'm not sure where from. Here is my powershell script:

```
$uni = Read-host 'Your username'

$SG = Read-host 'Security Group'

start-sleep -s 3

powershell.exe get-adgroupmember "$SG" | export-csv -path "C:\users\$uni\desktop\members.csv"
```

When opening the CSV, it shows similar:

## TYPE System.String

Length
79
79
63
17
34
79
26
54
1

Am I needing to declare or import a pssession? if so, what is the configurationname for active directory?

Comment: Remove `powershell.exe` and add `-NoTypeInformation` switch: `get-adgroupmember "$SG" | export-csv -path "C:\users\$uni\desktop\members.csv" -NoTypeInformation`.

Comment: I tried what you suggested, however I get a message within' cmd.exe, stating 'get-adgroupmember' is not recognized, so essentially it's trying to run the powershell command from cmd.exe rather than powershell. It stopped giving this error when I left powershell.exe in the begining.

Comment: You're not getting it from cmd.exe. You're getting a PowerShell exception - because `Get-ADGroupmember` is not a stock cmdlet. You need to import ActiveDirectory module first (and probably install RSAT to be able to do that).

Comment: copy that, I do have RSAT installed, and my AD Module is installed, but I understand exactly what you're getting at. Perhaps run an import in the PS1 script?
I did try, powershell.exe import-module ActiveDirectory | get-adgroupmember "$SG" yada yada... however get the same error.
Is there another way to import the module? I need it all on the same line essentially.

Comment: You sound terribly confused. First, like I said, you don't need to call powershell.exe inside a PowerShell script - drop it. Second, you shouldn't pipe output from `Import-Module` to `Get-ADGroupMember`. Instead make them separate commands. Perhaps [this example](http://serverfault.com/a/656498) can illustrate what I mean?

Comment: Holy cow I feel completely stupid, sorry for the confusion. You're right, I'm picking up what you're putting down. I managed to import the module and run the get command also was able to pipe the export but that example was perfect. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you're getting a collection of objects in your data. You have to expand or join the data before passing to Export-CSV

See the following articles for some idea:

1) http://blog.millersystems.com/powershell-exporting-multi-valued-attributes-via-export-csv-cmdlet/
2) http://www.msexchange.org/kbase/ExchangeServerTips/ExchangeServer2010/Powershell/WhydoIgetSystem.StringwhenusingGet-MessageTrackingLogandexportingtoaCSV.html

The articles give the following examples:

1) change the following

```
Get-TransportServer | Get-MessageTrackingLog -ResultSize -Start "11/28/2011" -Sender nuno@letsexchange.com | Select * | Export-Csv D:\Reports\Sent_Nuno.csv -NoType
```

to

```
Get-TransportServer | Get-MessageTrackingLog -ResultSize -Start "11/28/2011" -Sender nuno@letsexchange.com | Select {$_.Recipients}, {$_.RecipientStatus}, * | Export-Csv D:\Reports\Sent_Nuno.csv -NoType
```

2) change the following

```
Get-QADUser seth -IncludeAllProperties | select name, proxyaddresses | Export-Csv .seth-nojoin.csv - See more at: http://blog.millersystems.com/powershell-exporting-multi-valued-attributes-via-export-csv-cmdlet/#sthash.JCccKLui.dpuf
```

to

```
Get-QADUser seth -IncludeAllProperties | select name, @{Name=’proxyAddresses';Expression={[string]::join(“;”, ($_.proxyAddresses))}} | Export-Csv .seth-all_proxyaddresses.csv - See more at: http://blog.millersystems.com/powershell-exporting-multi-valued-attributes-via-export-csv-cmdlet/#sthash.JCccKLui.dpuf
```

You'll need to import the ActiveDirectory module for the get-ADGroupMember cmdlet, but I assume you've already gotten past that part as you have output instead of errors. I don't have the ability to test currently as I can't import the module (need RSAT or AD Management Gateway Service installed), but I think you would need to insert a select command in your pipeline (to enumerate the problematic data fields) that looks something like this:

```
powershell.exe get-adgroupmember "$SG" | Select {$_.nameOfVariableReturningSystemString}, * | export-csv -path "C:\users\$uni\desktop\members.csv
```

Comment: I tried this, I may be using the wrong variable in the select command, would the variable be like the name or email for example from AD? I just tried to target the same "#Type" that is listed when running the command directly from powershell (if that makes sense). I can go more into depth but I feel that this is definitely the direction I need to go.

Comment: Also yes the ad module is imported

Comment: Presumably your CSV has headers and the data in the column is displaying as System.String? If so, it'll be the name in the header of the problematic column ("Name", "Email", etc). Or are you talking about the very first line in the CSV? unless you use -notypeinformation when using export-csv, you'll get a line with the type information for the variable you exported.

Answer (score 0):

Alexander Obersht answered my question through comments, although duct_tape_coder you are also correct. Thanks for the help guys, appreciated.